# Cell reuse identifier in nib does not match the identifier

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, reuseidentifier

My app crashes instantly as soon as it tries to make the table view, no idea what is wrong since the cell reuse identifier in nib matches the identifier used to register the nib.
Would appreciate any help
I'm using a virtual machine, so I can't copy-paste the error, so here is a print:

Error message:

[image: Error Print]

```
2021-06-23 17:57:51.392316+0100
    ArmazemProcessador[8986:25810358] *** Assertion
    failure in -[UITableView
    _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:],
    /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple
    •xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3899.22
    •15 UITableView.m:8566
2021-06-23 17:57:51.396208+0100
    ArmazemProcessador[8986:25810358] *** Terminating
    app due to uncaught exception
    'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'cell
    reuse identifier in nib (CutomTableViewCell) does
    not match the identifier used to register the nib
    (CustomTableViewCell)'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Typo - `CutomTableViewCell` / `CustomTableViewCell`

Comment: holy, I was looking at this for 2 hours, losing hair from stress, even after your comment I had to print it and zoom in to tell the difference, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the crash -
[image]

It looks like -

1. `CustomTableViewCell.xib` has the `CutomTableViewCell` value in the reuse identifier.
2. When you did the `tableView.registerNib` call, you used `CustomTableViewCell` in the reuse identifier.

These reuse identifier values must match.

Comment: thank you, i somehow couldn't see the typo